# Target all users in two OU's and remove Distribution Lists

Tags: powershell, active-directory, distribution-list

hoping to get a little help here – I looked around the site but didn’t see anything quite like this (please direct me if there IS and I missed it).

I need to incorporate a new step in our user offboarding process, which would remove them from any AD Distribution Lists.  I would like to set this up as a scheduled task to run once a night against two OU’s where the inactivated user accounts can be found.

I’d like to run this by pointing it at the USERS instead of the OU where the Distro Lists live, because I suspect that we’ll ultimately get the request to remove these users from OTHER types of group as well.

This snippet will remove AD Distro Lists from a single user, but leave all other types of AD groups alone:

```
#  GroupCategory 0 = Distro List
#  GroupCategory 1 = Security Group

#  GroupScope 0 = DomainLocal
#  GroupScope 1 = Global
#  GroupScope 2 = Universal 

$user = "userlogon"
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user|
Where {$_.GroupCategory -eq 0} |
ForEach {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user -MemberOf $_ -Confirm:$false}
```

THIS snippet will look at an OU and return some info (just my example for using a variable with -searchbase):

```
$OUs = 'OU=PendingDeletion,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net','OU=HoldForReview,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net'


$OU | ForEach {Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties ManagedBy -SearchBase $_ } |
 Select Name, ManagedBy |
 Sort -Property Name
 Out-GridView
```

BUT – Does it hold together that in order to complete my objective, I would do something like this?!  I'm a bit out of my depth here, any advice for a re-write is appreciated:

```
$OUs = 'OU=PendingDeletion,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net','OU=HoldForReview,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net'
 $user = "*"

$OUs | ForEach {
        Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user|
        Where {$_.GroupCategory -eq 0} |
        ForEach {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user -MemberOf $_ -Confirm:$false}
              }
```

There’s always a couple of ways to do stuff in PoSh, so I’m sure there’s a less-complicated way to do the same thing.  If anyone has a different approach please feel free to suggest an alternative.

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you need three loops.

First, you will need to loop over the OU list to get the Users. We'll store the user objects in `$Users`

```
$OUs = 'OU=PendingDeletion,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net','OU=HoldForReview,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net'
$Users = ForEach ($OU in $OUs) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU 
}
```

Next loop over the users to get the groups that you want to remove. Then loop over the groups to remove each one.

```
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user |
    Where-Object {$_.GroupCategory -eq 0} |
    ForEach-Object {
        Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user -MemberOf $_
    }
}
```

Comment: Very cool - looks so simple in retrospect!  I have another step that I'd like to add, but I'm marking this one as solved for now!

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd take this a little differently, by getting the group membership of all users, then grouping by AD group, and processing each group that way. Seems like it would be a lot fewer calls to AD. So I'd start out getting all of the users, just like BenH, except I would include their MemberOf property. Then I'd build a list of potential groups and filter down to just the Distribution Lists. I'd make a Hashtable of those as the keys, and make the value an array of each user that is in that group. Then loop through that removing the value of each from the associated key.

```
$OUs = 'OU=PendingDeletion,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net','OU=HoldForReview,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net'
$Users = ForEach ($OU in $OUs) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU -Properties MemberOf
}
$UsersByGroup = @{}
ForEach($Group in ($Users.MemberOf | Select -Unique | Get-ADGroup | Where{ $_.GroupCategory -eq 0 })) {
    $UsersByGroup.Add($Group.DistinguishedName,($Users | Where{ $Group.DistinguishedName -in $_.MemberOf}))
}
$UsersByGroup.Keys | ForEach{
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $UsersByGroup[$_] -Confirm:$false
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that is ALSO very cool.  I have to confess that I don't understand this one quite as well as I understand BenH's answer but I tried marking them both as answers, because I think they're both valid approaches.  Sorry that I can't also give this answer credit!

Comment: If you have any specific questions feel free to ask and I'll do my best to explain things.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm actually wrestling with the first part of the script where it collects all the users...  I need to incorporate some logic to limit the collected users to only the ones with an expiration date in AD of more than 30 days ago.  I didn't want to encourage "scope-creep" after my initial question was answered, so I posted another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377866/target-all-users-in-two-ous-and-remove-distribution-lists-adding-date-criteri) - my first steps and questions are over there if you feel like taking a look!.