# Target all users in two OU's and remove Distribution Lists - Adding date criteria

Tags: powershell, active-directory, distribution-list

@BenH and @TheMadTechnician were extremely helpful in assisting me with a script, to remove Distro Lists (only) from users in specific AD OU's.  I forgot to add a needed criteria, so decided to post this as a separate question (original thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373637/target-all-users-in-two-ous-and-remove-distribution-lists/44375476#44375476))

@BenH's approach was like this:

```
$OUs = 'OU=PendingDeletion,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net','OU=HoldForReview,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net'
$Users = ForEach ($OU in $OUs) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU 
}

ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user |
    Where-Object {$_.GroupCategory -eq 0} |
    ForEach-Object {
        Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user -MemberOf $_
    }
}
```

**My question - can I force the script to only take action on accounts that have expired more than 30days ago**, by adding a variable and "Where-Object" logic to the first loop like this?:

```
    $OUs = 'OU=PendingDeletion,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net','OU=HoldForReview,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net'
    $30DaysOld = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

    $Users = ForEach ($OU in $OUs) {
        Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU |
        Where-Object {$_.AccountExpirationDate -gt $30DaysOld}}

    ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user |
    Where-Object {$_.GroupCategory -eq 0} |
    ForEach-Object {
        Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user -MemberOf $_
    }
}
```

Possible?  Or would I need to change the `-gt` to a `-lt` in order to get the correct date range?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Your question is "I have written this code, does it work"? Well ... does it work? Does it get you the accounts you expect?

Comment: You would want `-lt`. Here's a comparison statement that should illustrate: `(Get-Date).AddDays(-30) -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-40)` is `$True`. You could add `-WhatIf` to your `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` to see what the command would try to execute.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - solid point, sorry I was not more clear.  Upon review, my question wasn't phrased very well.

The first loop is NOT collecting the correct users; checking the contents of  the variable `$Users`, AccountExpirationDate showed blank.  I changed the line to:

`Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties AccountExpirationDate -SearchBase $OU`

Now I see the Exp Date as listed on the AD account, but using `-lt` returns all the users, with or without expiration dates in AD, and `-gt` returns no users.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with the formatting?  `get-aduser test1 -Properties name, AccountExpirationDate` returns "4/21/2017 12:00:00 AM", whereas checking the contents of the variable `$30DaysOld` returns "Sunday, May 07, 2017 3:10:10 PM"

Comment: Perhaps `Where{$_.AccountExpirationDate -lt $30DaysOld -and $_.AccountExpirationDate}` would work for you. That makes sure they're more than 30 days old, and makes sure that the value isn't `$null`. If you still feel that too many results are being generated, go and look at the dates. Are there actually any that expired less than 30 days ago, or have not yet expired?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - that was the very thing, you're the bomb!  Now it returns correct results in all test cases.

Now that I have a viable solution in place, I'll circle back and take a look at the code that you proposed in my initial thread.

Thanks for the hand-holding, I wish I could mark your comment as the answer.  If you want to re-submit AS the answer, I will certainly update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an answer as requested. The problem is with the `Where` statement:

```
Where-Object {$_.AccountExpirationDate -gt $30DaysOld}
```

While logically is sounds like it's right *'where the account expired more than 30 days ago'* it actually comes out to *'where the Date that the account expired is greater than what the Date was 30 days ago'*. When you consider that some systems measure dates as seconds passed since the Unix Epoch (Jan 1, 1970 at 12:00:00 AM UTC), and dates are converted to integers, and it makes more sense that the `-gt` operator selects whichever date happens later chronologically as more seconds have passed since the epoch, and the integer is a larger number.

If you change the `-gt` to `-lt` it accomplishes what you're looking for. Also, adding `-and $_.AccountExpirationDate` to it makes sure that the `AccountExpirationDate` is not null. So we end up with:

```
Where-Object {$_.AccountExpirationDate -lt $30DaysOld -and $_.AccountExpirationDate}
```

Answer (score 0):

[@TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377866/target-all-users-in-two-ous-and-remove-distribution-lists-adding-date-criteri/45019238#comment75932617_44377866) nailed it:

> Perhaps `Where{$_.AccountExpirationDate -lt $30DaysOld -and $_.AccountExpirationDate}` would work for you. That makes sure they're more than 30 days old, and makes sure that the value isn't `$null`. If you still feel that too many results are being generated, go and look at the dates. Are there actually any that expired less than 30 days ago, or have not yet expired?

I needed to change the nested "where" statement to:

```
 Where-Object {$_.AccountExpirationDate -lt $30DaysOld -and $_.AccountExpirationDate}
```

So the functioning code is:

```
$30DaysOld = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$OUs = 'OU=PendingDeletion,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net','OU=HoldForReview,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net'

$Users = ForEach ($OU in $OUs) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties AccountExpirationDate -SearchBase $OU  |
    Where-Object {$_.AccountExpirationDate -lt $30DaysOld -and $_.AccountExpirationDate}
    }

ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user |
    Where-Object {$_.GroupCategory -eq 0} |
    ForEach-Object {
        Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user -MemberOf $_ -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**OP here** - I've been continuing to work on this (with assistance), and added some additional embellishments that I thought someone else might find useful, so I wanted to share it back.

[TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377866/target-all-users-in-two-ous-and-remove-distribution-lists-adding-date-criteri/44528228#44528228) and [BenH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377866/target-all-users-in-two-ous-and-remove-distribution-lists-adding-date-criteri/44508643#comment75786239_44377866) deserve all the credit for breaking the back of this.

This will now write the names of distros removed to the AD account, use a semicolon separator (to cut/paste the names if you need to re-add the distros), and won't add clutter to the AD account if it's run against the account more than once.

```
#  Variables

$30DaysOld = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$OUs = (
  'OU=PendingDeletion,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net',
  'OU=HoldForReview,OU=Users,DC=Stuff,DC=Place,DC=net'
)

#  Collect the needed users

$Users = ForEach ($OU in $OUs) {
  Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties AccountExpirationDate,info -SearchBase $OU |
  Where-Object {$_.AccountExpirationDate -lt $30DaysOld -and $_.AccountExpirationDate}
}
 
#  Collect each user's Distro Lists & REMOVE

ForEach ($User in $Users) {
  $distrosremoved=@()
 
  Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user |
  Where-Object {$_.GroupCategory -eq "distribution"} |
  ForEach-Object {
    $distrosremoved+=$_.name
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user -MemberOf $_ -Confirm:$false
  }
  
  #  Collect info from the Telephone > Notes field, and ADD the list of Distros into the existing info

  if($distrosremoved){
 
      $distro_str="Removed Distro Lists: `r`n"+($distrosremoved -join "; ")
 
      if ($user.info){
        $newinfo=$user.info+"`r`n"+$distro_str
        Set-ADUser $user -Replace @{info=$newinfo}
      }else{
        $newinfo=$distro_str
        Set-ADUser $user -Add @{info=$distro_str}
      }
  }
}
```